# Failed to start openvpn-client@clientudp.service: Unit -.mount is masked

Tags: fedora, openvpn

I can't start my openvpn on fedora anymore. I'm getting an error: Failed to start openvpn-client@clientudp.service: Unit -.mount is masked after sudo systemctl start openvpn-client@clientudp.service

Which .mount file responsible for ovpn client?

Answer (score 0):

Removing ".mount" files have helped. That's what I did:

```
sudo rm /run/systemd/system/-.mount
sudo rm /run/systemd/system/tmp.mount
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start openvpn-client@clientudp.service
```